# Idiomatic way to chain redux state changes?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, reselect

I'm trying to figure out the idiomatic way to address this:

I have a reducer that contains a list of “applied filters” and a list of “records”.  When I change the filters or records, a list of “filtered records” should also change, but applying the filters to what can be a long list of records can be slow-ish.

Right now, I’m dispatching an “Add filter” or “Remove filter” action to change that list of “applied filters”. This results in recalculating the list of “filtered records” (currently done in the reducer).

I'm using two container components, one to display a list of "filter chips", the other to display the list of "filtered records".

Because applying the filters takes a while, and is done every time the filters change, the process of removing a filter from the UI seems laggy -- I click to remove a filter, and the removed filter doesn't disappear until the reducer finishes all its work, which includes updating the list of filters AND applying the new list of filters.

What I'd rather have is:

1. Remove the filter, and it disappears from the UI as quickly as possible. (i.e., a state change is broadcast that just includes the removed filter)
2. Concurrently, I'd like the process of applying the filters to occur in the background, and once that is finished, dispatch another action to change the list of filtered records.
3. After the filters have been applied and the action to update the filtered records has fired, I want my "filtered records list" component to update.

So, essentially I want a state change to potentially trigger ANOTHER state change, but I want to broadcast the intermediate state in between those two state changes.

I know I have to get the bulky logic out of my reducers and into an action, but I'm struggling with how/where that logic should be applied. I have that nagging feeling that I've wrapped my brain around its axle and I'm now overcomplicating things, but I can't seem to get back to the simple/correct method.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

---

Edit, from a comment I added, but wanted to keep it inline here as well:

I mis-spoke in my original question, pretty big correction here --

I'm not actually calculating the "filtered record list" in the reducer -- I have a reselect selector on my "RecordList" container that takes in "records" and "filters" and returns a list of the filtered records.

I'm thinking this is more because of the "RecordList" render holding up the "FilterList"  render, so I'm going to go up the component hierarchy and see if I can fix something there.

I'd still be up for any suggestions, though!

Comment: I mis-spoke in my original question, pretty big correction here --

I'm not actually calculating the "filtered record list" in the reducer -- I have a reselect selector on my "RecordList" container that takes in "records" and "filters" and returns a list of the filtered records.

I'm thinking this is more because of the "RecordList" render holding up the "FilterList"  render, so I'm going to go up the component hierarchy and see if I can fix something there.

I'd still be up for any suggestions, though!

Comment: As a first suggestion, you should probably run some perf profiling to see where the bottleneck actually is.  I have a list of links to articles on React/Redux perf topics at https://github.com/markerikson/react-redux-links/blob/master/react-performance.md .  Also, "it's laggy" doesn't really provide much actionable info.  Can you clarify the behavior?  What makes you say the reducer is the issue?